# Experimental set-up for coin frequency analysis

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment

As part of my school project, I need to drop an object from a constant height (the height here is the controlled variable). Beyond just physically measuring the distance of free fall, is there any method/idea I could use to ensure that the height remains constant?

Thanks!

Comment: Saying that "height remains constant" itself means that "physical distance remains constant", and that's what you have to measure. Yes it will have an error of precision, but any other indirect method, like measuring time of fall and velocity at the bottom, etc. will also be errorful.

Comment: push the object off your table,  distance from table-top to floor should remain reasonably constant.

Comment: @Jasen, doing so would mean that I would have to account for the force with which I push the object, which may or may not remain constant.

Comment: So push it off slowly. Or with a uniform mechanism involving a spring. If you are just attempting to get repeatability (a good idea) then *set up something repeatable*. At the level of a 'school project' you are suppose to be developing basic skills, not wowing the scientific world.  But think when you do it ... if the analysis is about the statistics of a flipped coin, would it be good do drop it without spin?